# How do I start properly Django project?

Tags: django, fatal-error, launcher

I wrote
`C:\Users\jj>django-admin startproject mysite`
And the results are
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\django-admin.exe" startproject mysite'`

I tried to start my first django project, but It wont open. I can't find any solutions to this problem on the internet and I have not idea what to do next

Comment: what is the output of `pip show django` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

same problem, when i was creating my first project. so i am giving you some solutions given below:

1. you can change directory of your project.
2. have you run the server? if not then use this command `py manage.py runserver`
3. otherwise you can use this [https://www.w3schools.com/django/]